# What's the source for the phrase in Krias Shema al HaMitah: : ...בְּשֵׁם יְיָ אֱלֹקֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל and to recite it 3x?

Tags: sources-mekorot, ashkenazi, shema, sleep, malach-angel

What's the source for the actual phrase that is cited in Krias Shema al HaMitah: בְּשֵׁם יְיָ אֱלֹקֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל: מִימִינִי מִיכָאֵל וּמִשְּׂמֹאלִי גַבְרִיאֵל וּמִלְּפָנַי אוּרִיאֵל וּמֵאֲחוֹרַי רְפָאֵל וְעַל רֹאשִׁי שְׁכִינַת אֵל? And where is the source for the minhag to recite it 3x?

The concept of these angels and how they are situated is brought in Bamidbar Rabah 2, Pirkei D'Rebbi Eliezer 4, and other Midrashim; however, the actual phrase which is printed in every Siddur (ashkenaz) seems to appear from nowhere. I can't find any mention of even reciting this phrase in the poskim either (ie Tur, Mishnah Berurah, Chayei Adam, Levush, etc).

Comment: adtz, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for posting this question. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site.

Answer (score 1):

All texts and links below from this extensive [article](http://upload-community.kipa.co.il/5420112511.doc):

It is first mentioned in the [Siddur of Rashi](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=252) - albeit in a slightly different version:

> מימיני מיכאל משמאלי גבריאל, מאחורי אוריאל, מלפני רפאל ושכינת אל על ראשי.

R' Pinchas Eliyahu of Vilna writes in [Sefer Habris](http://hebrewbooks.org/30819) that

> ואתה בן אדם שים פניך לדבר הזה מן היום הזה ומעלה שתרגיל את עצמך בכל עת ובכל שעה בשבתך בביתך ובלכתך בדרך ובשכבך ובקומך לדמות בדמיונך ולצייר במחשבתך כי שם ה' נקרא עליך תמיד זורח הוא ממעל לראשך וכאלו אתה עומד תחת כסא הכבוד וסעד בחסד כסאו עליך ויתן את כסאו ממעל לראשך באהבתו ובחמלתו עליך תיכף מן היום אשר נתת לבך לדבר הזה כי אהבך ה' אלהיך וכי אהב את אבותיך ויבחר בזרעם אחריהם... ועל סוד הזה **תקנו לנו קדמונינו לאמר קודם השכיבה מימיני מיכאל ומשמאלי גבריאל מלפני אוריאל ומאחורי רפאל ועל ראשי שכינת אל, ואז בלי ספק שתעורר את האהבה אליו ואהבת את ה' אלהיך בכל לבבך ובכל נפשך ובכל מאדך** ותאמר אהבתי את אדוני והיית אך שמח וטוב לב את ה' אלהיך אשר זכה אותך את כל הכבוד הגדול הזה ותאמר הלא הוא טהור ומשרתיו טהורים אין קדוש כה' מלך גדול ונורא... , ונמצא מלבד מה שתביאך האהבה לקיום עשר מצות המחשביים האמורים למעלה  תביאך ג"כ לשמוח בו בהכרח כי פעמים רבות ידע לבך נוכח פניך היה  שענין האהבה היא שמחת הנפש: והנה השמחה הזו היא מצוה גדולה עד מאד כי היא שמחה של כל המצות כי הלא הוא שש ועלץ במה שהוא עבד ה' והיה כאשר שש על זאת הן הוא משוש כל המצות וכל התורה והשמחה הזה היא יקרה בעיני ה' מאד, אף חובב אותה ביותר ומקפיד עליה הרבה כנאמר תחת אשר לא עבדת את ה' אלהיך בשמחה ובטוב לבב (דברים כ"ח), ואנו מוזהרים עליה כנאמר עבדו את ה' בשמחה (תהלים ק'), ונאמר גילו ושמחו בה' (יואל ב').

That is, that by saying 'Beshem Hashem', one will mystically be filled with love for Hashem, and be filled with joy - the highest level in serving Hashem.

R, SR Hirsch writes in his Siddur p729:

> It is "in the Name of God," at His command, that His angels surround you, Michael, performing His unique miracles; Gabriel, the messenger of His almighty power; Uriel, who bears the light of God before you; Raphael, who brings you healing from Him; and above your head, you have the presence of God himself.

Accordingly, it takes on the form of a prayer, asking permission to reside among the angels and among the Shechina itself.

The article makes no mention of why it is said 3 times, though.